# How can I perform Model Binding using SelectMethod when the query returns no records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, entity-framework-6

I have a ListView control and I'm using Model Binding with the SelectMethod property.  I am using ASP.NET 4.5 with Entity Framework 6.  Now in the select method if there are any records found, the ListView loads fine.  However, if the SelectMethod function returns null, meaning it does not return any records I receive a NullReferenceException.  I would like to continue using the ListView with the SelectMethod but without this exception (i.e. load an empty list view).  Is this possible?  Or do I have to remove the SelectMethod property and load this manually from an event handler in code-behind?

**Sample Code**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvBankAccounts" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="Id" ItemType="Models.BankAccountInfo" SelectMethod="GetBankAccounts">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <%# Item.BankName %>
        </div>
        .
        .
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

// Select Method
public IQueryable<Models.BankAccountInfo> GetBankAccounts()
{
    int Id;
    int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out Id);
    Models.BankAccountInfo acct = dbContext.BankAccounts.Find(Id);
    if (acct != null)
    {
        return dbContext.BankAccounts.Where(account => account.Id == acct.Id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is IQueryable, so you should return an IQueryable, e.g.

```
var query = from ba in dbContext.BankAccounts
            where ba.Id == acct.Id
            select ba;

return query;
```

and let the listview deal with a 'blank / null' IQueryable if the query returns no records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a message when no data exists implement the EmptyDataTemplate:

// in your .aspx

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvBankAccounts" runat="server">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No data available.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  Actually, that was one of the first things I tried.  Even with the EmptyDataTemplate it gives me the error:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ModelDataSourceView.FindMethod(String methodName) +160